# getting error on sql query in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using this sql query in c#

```
select t.testname,t.totalque,r.testdate,r.score 
from test t, result r 
where t.testid=r.testid 
  and r.login='vsdep980'
```

but it shows an error that is

> invalid column name 'vsdep980'

now here `vsdep980` is the value which is stored in the column `login` but why it shows this type of error.

now my code is

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select t.testname,t.totalque,r.testdate,r.score from test t, result r where t.testid=r.testid and r.login=vsdep980", con);
con.Open();
int c = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
con.Close();
if (c > 0)
{
    Response.Write("<br><br><h1 class='head1'> You have not given any quiz</h1>");
    Response.End();
}
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
DataRow dr = null;
Response.Write("<table border='1' align='center'><tr class='style2'><td width='300'>Test Name </td><td> Total<br> Question </td><td> Date </td><td> Score </td></tr>");
foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
{
    dr = dr1;
    Response.Write("<tr class='style8'><td> "+dr[0]+" </td><td align='center'> "+dr[1]+" </td><td align='center'> "+dr[2]+" </td><td align='center'>"+dr[3]+" </td></tr>");
}
Response.Write("</table>");
```

image of error msg

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Bad habits to kick, do not use old joins.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand..   Please explain it.

Comment: Do you get the same error in SSMS?

Comment: Did you run this query in SQL Server? what you get?

Comment: show us your  c# code. That code should run ok in SQL-Server

Comment: Did you try using inner join instead of using conditions?

Comment: yes ofcourse this code is running well in sqlserver but in c# it shows an error.

Comment: Ok. Please post your C# code.

Comment: ok i am posting..

Comment: Please show the c# code that is using this query

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: look at the question i have posted my query

Comment: Enclose `vsdep980` in single quotes.

Comment: You don't have single quotes around `vsdep980` in your C# code.  SQL Server is treating it as a column name and not a string literal.

Comment: @squillman single quotes shows also a new error that is "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @V.Deep Then you did it wrong.  What did you type?  It should be `"...and r.login='vsdep980' "`

Comment: @squillman i have written this
"select t.testname,t.totalque,r.testdate,r.score from test t, result r where t.testid=r.testid and r.login='vsdep980' "

Comment: please look at question i have also added my error screen..

Comment: You don't need to escape the single quotes in c#

Comment: If i am not using escape still the same error shows.

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row of the query, which in your case is test name. Converting a test name into an integer will fail. Use string instead

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah thank u sir. It works ..  thanks for helping me.

Comment: My pleasure. As a general policy, if an answer solves your question, please mark it as answer as this will help the community be more organised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing a query that returns multiple columns (and, I'm assuming multiple rows) with a call to `ExecuteScalar()`.  This method is primarily used for retrieving a single value from SQL Server (it returns the value from the first column of the first row of your data).  I expect that the first value of `t.testname` is not convertable to an `Int32`.

From your code, it looks like you're trying to check to see if any rows are returned from your query.  If that is the case, you should do something like this instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select t.testname,t.totalque,r.testdate,r.score from test t, result r where t.testid=r.testid and r.login='vsdep980'", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    Response.Write("<br><br><h1 class='head1'> You have not given any quiz</h1>");
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1- Do not use old joins.

> [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

2- Use parameters in your query.

> A parameterized query is a query in which placeholders are used for parameters and the parameter values are supplied at execution time. The most important reason to use parameterized queries is to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Your query should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select t.testname,t.totalque,r.testdate,r.score 
from test t, result r where t.testid=r.testid and r.login='vsdep980'", con);
```

You miss quote `''`, so the `vsdep980` will act as a column instead of a value.

And your query should be like:

```
SELECT T.testname,
       T.totalque,
       R.testdate,
       R.score 
FROM test T JOIN result R ON T.testid = R.testid -- Use the new style instead
WHERE R.login = 'vsdep980';
```

Comment: if i use single quote it shows again a new error "input string was not in the correct format"

Comment: Try using the single quotes with the escape sequence like I've mentioned i.e. \'vsdep980\'

Comment: I've added more details in the question's comments section

Answer (score 1):

The query has to use single quotes while specifying the filter text i.e vsdep980.

Edit: Looking at the code I saw that the command is executed using ExecuteScalar. ExecuteScalar executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Since the first column is testname it'll return a string that cannot be converted to an integer. Rethink what you want to do with the return value and change it accordingly